# Git repository structure for c#/.net projects for small teams

Tags: c#, .net, git

I am looking at moving our .net(c#) projects from TFS to git. The general consensus in the tema that we do not want to continue with tfs has been reached and we wish to trial git. We currentley do not have that many projects to migrate over but we expect these to grow as our old systems are replaced.

Currently we have a tfs project for all things that we think will be needed by multiple projects, database stuff, 3rd party dll's etc. What is the best way to have a similar structure in git?

The best way I could see is to have a similar thing to our current structure, with a seperate repository for all the common files.
I have read about using submodules but there seems to be a lot of complaints about these. Is it worth trying something like repo or another alternative? Or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: I would go with separate repositories for logic parts of your projects. I think submodules are only relevant if you need another existing git repo inside your own repo. But in your case separate repositories should be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

This question is going to be pretty subjective, but IMO I would solve this by having a separate repository for your common stuff.

Another option is to migrate your common stuff to [Nuget packages](https://www.google.com/search?q=private+nuget+repository) so you can move your common stuff forward without worrying about breaking all your existing projects.

**In my experience common projects in an Enterprise environment tend to calcify your ability to respond to change quickly.** Instead you spend lot's of time worrying about how changes in your "Core" or "Lib" modules will affect the 80+ projects you have that are using them. Worse, people just start shoving everything into those modules even if it is only pertinent to a few projects simply because it's *easy*.